# Fiddleで構造体を関数に渡す方法

Tags: ruby

※ 小生、C言語には疎く根本的なことを理解していない可能性がありますが、質問させていただきたく。

Ruby の Fiddle を使って構造体を引数に取る関数を定義したいのですが以下のコードだとエラーが出ます。何が間違っているのでしょうか？

```rb
module MyDll
    require 'fiddle'
    require 'fiddle/import'
    require 'fiddle/types'
    
    extend Fiddle::Importer
    dlload %q(C:\dev\source\repos\Dll1\x64\Debug\Dll1.dll)
    include Fiddle::Win32Types

    Struct1 = struct([
        'short a',
        'short b',
    ])

    extern 'int add(Struct1)'
end

struct1 = MyDll::Struct1.malloc
struct1.a = 1
struct1.b = 2

p MyDll.add(struct1)
```

実行したときのエラーは以下の通りです

```
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle/cparser.rb:247:in `parse_ctype': unknown type: Struct1 (Fiddle::DLError)
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle/cparser.rb:117:in `block in parse_signature'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle/cparser.rb:117:in `collect'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle/cparser.rb:117:in `parse_signature'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fiddle/import.rb:168:in `extern'
        from ./fiddle.rb:15:in `<module:MyDll>'
        from ./fiddle.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

C側のコードは以下の通りです。

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct _Struct1 {
    short a;
    short b;
} Struct1;

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall add(Struct1 s);
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall add1(Struct1 *s);
}

int add(Struct1 s) {
    return s.a + s.b;
}

int add1(Struct1 *s) {
    return s->a + s->b;
}
```

ruby のバージョンは `ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [x64-mingw-ucrt]` でした。

Ruby・Cのコード両方のaddの引数を `Struct1` から `Struct1*` に変更すると期待した動作になりますが、ポインタを渡すことが必須なのでしょうか？

Comment: 某所でこのことについての議論が行われましたが、Fiddleでは難しく、Ruby-FFI を使うしかないのではないか？ということになりました。その内容が正しいかどうかはわかりませんが参考まで。。。

Comment: @kojix2 貴重な情報ありがとうございます。承知しました。Ruby-FFIを使うようにします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) のコード

```
struct1 = MyDll::Struct1.malloc
struct1.a = 1
struct1.b = 2
```

を [c](/questions/tagged/c) に翻訳するなら

```
Struct1* struct1 = malloc(sizeof(Struct1));
struct1->a = 1
struct1->b = 2
```

相当です。だからその `struct1` を素直に [c](/questions/tagged/c) に渡すのであれば `int add1(Struct1* s) {...}` で受けろ、ということになります。
# どうしても `int add(Struct1 s)` を呼びたいって場合にどうすればよいかは未調査